# how paintcomponent method in the followong program executed?

Tags: jpanel

This is the program for adding and spreading the image on jpanel...This program works fine...giving results perfectly...but i don't understand how override paint component executed and who calls it....

```
       import java.awt.Graphics;

      import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

       import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

      import java.io.File; 

      import java.io.FileInputStream;

      import java.io.IOException;

     import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{


private BufferedImage image;


public ImagePanel() {

   try {

       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("e:\\pic1.jpg");

       BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);

      image = ImageIO.read(bis);

   } catch (IOException ex) {

   }

   JFrame jf=new JFrame();

   jf.add(this);

   jf.setSize(300,300);

   jf.setVisible(true);

}


protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(image,0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ImagePanel();
}

}
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

The paint-methods are called by the event dispatch thread (EDT) of AWT/Swing. This thread in a loop permanently processes events and your UI related tasks that you submit via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and updates the UI when necessary. This results in your method being called. You can verify that by calling `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` or `Thread.currentThread().getName()` from within that method. If you want to trigger this manually, don't call the paint method itself, call `repaint()`.